# FontFamily reference in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've a font family called VLADIMIR.ttf.But I'm not setting this font to my textblock object.How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks for your help.

Here is code:

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEF7777"/>        
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Ideal"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/ApplicationName;Component/Resources/#VLADIMIR"/>        
</Style>
```

I set build action property "Content" or "Resource".But Font familiy hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you need to follow this syntax when setting your FontFamily:

```
"/FontPath/FontFileName.ttf#FontName"
```

for example, I've create a folder in my solution named "/Fonts", in which i added the VLADIMIR.ttf font :

```
<TextBlock Text="This is text block" FontFamily="/Fonts/VLADIMIR.TTF#Vladimir Script"/>
```

don't forget to set the "Build Action" of the font to "Content" and The "Copy To Output Directory" To "Copy always"

Answer (score 0):

Set build action to `Resource` and change your value to:

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/ApplicationName;component/Resources/#Vladimir Script"/>
```

Comment: Do I need to use the "Script" word whole font familiy.Thanks by the way.

Comment: `Vladimir Script` is the name of your font. So yes, you'll have to use that.